# How do I gain knowledge about various monsters?

Tags: the-witcher-2

Everytime I kill a monster I gain a count towards knowledge of that monster.  I've gotten enough kills(bottom corner shows 3/3), which *should* be the same as reading a book on that monster.  However, when I go into my journal, it doesn't show any entries on that monster and I still need to read the book.  Is this a bug?  How do I fix it?

Comment: Say what?... Punctuations.. ever heard of them?

Answer (score 2):

A bit to late to the party, but I think you might be looking into the wrong place. The information acquired via fighting will not be in the journal, but in your character attributes screen. One of the buttons on the right will show you your "monster knowledge".